# RegEx and glob()

Tags: php, regex, glob

So here is my problem.

I want to select only those files from the folder, which name contains only letters and numbers with specific file extensions.

Here is the pattern

```
$files = glob($somedir.'/[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,71}.{jpeg,png}',GLOB_BRACE);
```

When I print it out `print_r($files)` it returns an empty array.

Is it possible to use regex with glob() and which part should I correct in my code?

If there is something I can improve in my question, let me know.

Comment: Take a look at this [nice article](http://www.cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/). Also logically speaking, you're using `{jpeg,png}` to match either `jpeg` or `png` while you also use `{4,71}` which you meant as quantifier. I think you might forget about `glob()` and use `scandir()` with `preg_grep()` so that you can use more powerful regex

Comment: I know that {4,71} means a quantifier in my case and I'm already reading that article, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @HamZa, What's the difference between `preg_match` and `preg_grep`?

Comment: I would say take a look at this [example](https://eval.in/138733) and check the manual :)

Comment: @HamZa, excellent! Post your comment (the code) as an answer!

Comment: I'm actually hesitating if that is the "best" method. I'm thinking about what if the directory is so big that the resulting array will try to use more memory than it is allowed (which will throw an error)?

Comment: How big do you think the directory should be, that will result in an error?

Comment: It depends on the array that is generated and the limits you have in your php config. Short answer: I don't know

Answer (score 1):

This is where SPL's iterators can be very useful as an alternative to glob(), allowing you to use a full regexp

```
class ImageFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    // overwriting the accept method to perform a super simple test to
    // determine if the files found were images (types we want at least) or 
    // not..
    public function accept() {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{4,71}\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',$this->getExtension())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 


$path = dirname(__FILE__);

foreach(new ImageFilterIterator(new FilesystemIterator($path)) as $image) {
    echo $image, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe using directly `return (bool) preg_match(...);` is better and less redundant or is it "hacky"?

Comment: Arguable whether it's hacky or not; but this answer is intended as a pointer to the powerful options available within SPL's iterators and an example showing how to use FilterIterator, so the more obvious if/else structure shouldn't get in the way of the SPL side of the answer

Comment: Better coding would certainly have been to move the `return false` outside of the `else`, and then drop the `else`

Answer (score 0):

`glob()` does not work with regular expressions, only with shell patterns - see [its documentation](http://php.net/glob). And they are limited.

You can use a loop instead along these lines:

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir($somedir);
while (($fname = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,71}\.(jpeg|png)$/', $fname))
    $files[] = "$somedir/$fname";
}
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: I know they don't, but thought there might be some pattern which would work in my case.

Comment: Using `preg_match` in a loop is a really bad idea. You might look into `preg_grep()`

Comment: I think the best you can do is to do `????*`, which will match anything 4 characters long or more.